# X11 forwarding seems not working?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11

i am using ubuntu 16.04. The Server is also running ubuntu 16.04.

my  `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` looks so:

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

server `sshd_config`:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

When i connect to a ssh Server :

```
ssh -vvv -Y server
```

ssh connects to the server.
When i running something like xclock this happens:

```
debug3: receive packet: type 90
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 2 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 59790
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
debug3: send packet: type 91
```

The terminal also dies after this i have to restart a new terminal.
No clock is showing up on local pc also there is no error... Any idea? When i try the same from Win 10 with xming and putty it works. Server has activated x11 forwarding.

Comment: Using "trusted" connections is a very VERY bad idea.

Comment: Are you actually running a X server on the machine you use to connect, or is it running Wayland?

Answer (score 0):

One detail of configuration that I have stumbled over in the past, and could possibly be causing your trouble, is clarified by one sentence in **man sshd_config**.  Also, **man ssh_config** says something similar.

> For each keyword, the first obtained value will be used.

This seems counterintuitive to me, but if you have the same line with different values in ssh_config and/or ~/.ssh/config on the machine your using, it's the ***first*** one that will take effect.  Later ones will be ignored.

Same for sshd_config on the distant machine.